# How is replaceable text shown in a terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, text-user-interface

For example after doing `apt-get update`, it shows
`Reading package lists... 82%` with the percentage changing in the same line.

How is that achieved? Is it possible to use it in a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you haven't output new line yet (e,g: used *-n* in echo command) , the command:

```
echo -e "\r\033["
```

will do the trick.

Comment: What is `\033[` part meant to do? It seems `\r` should be enough to do carriage return.

Comment: it should remove the text shown (`\r` get you back to the start of the line, but if you don't write anything the text won't be removed)
now I checked this on few other terminals, and the `\033[` behaves differently in any terminal, so I would recommend not to use it in scripts.

Comment: To clear the terminal instead of just doing carriage return I'd suggest something like `printf \\r%${COLUMNS}s\\r ' '`.

Answer (score 2):

Terminals understand escape sequences to move the cursor around, change the text color and other actions. These escape sequences are recorded in the [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) and [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) databases as they differ between terminal types (altough most terminal types today mostly implement the same escape sequences).

You can record the full output of an application with the [script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unix%29) utility.

```
script -c 'apt-get update' apt-get.script
```

`apt-get` keeps things simple: it only uses the control character [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (known as CR, Ctrl+M, `\r`, …) which moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line.